# java.io.FileNotFoundException - Support needed

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using netbean 7.0. I've completed a project and after build the project I get build failed and below is the error details:

```
------
pre-init:
init-private:
init-userdir:
init-user:
init-project:
do-init:
post-init:
init-check:
init:
deps-jar:
deps-j2ee-archive:

C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\osing\nbproject\build-impl.xml:210: The following error occurred while executing this line:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\helen\WORKSPACE\Java\osing\osing-ejb\build.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:278)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

---

Can anyone please advise me on how I can go about resolving this to enable to build the project

Answer (score 2):

This file `C:\Users\helen\WORKSPACE\Java\osing\osing-ejb\build.xml` does not exist in your system. Analyzing this path as well as the path to your build-impl.xml `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\osing\nbproject\build-impl.xml` I can say that probably you copied this project from other user. Your user name is osing. You copied it from user helen.

But for some reason the project contains absolute paths that do not exist on your system. If my assumptions are correct first fix the path to build.xml into build-impl.xml and make the project to compile. Then fix the project using environment variables or/and *relative* paths so that other users can use it without changes.

Comment: Alex, I did copy receive the project from helen and simply open it in netbean 7.0 and did some changes. Any idea on how to fix it following you method with netbean

Comment: @user1027292, I wrote the ideas. Fix path of file that does not exist on your system. When  you make your project to work change all absolute paths to variables. I know how to do this in Eclipse, but NetBeans must support this too.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for this file but failing to find it: C:\Users\helen\WORKSPACE\Java\osing\osing-ejb\build.xml

Without knowing how your project is set up, that's all I can tell you...

Comment: Well I just got the project file and open it in netbean

Answer (score 0):

check file `build.xml` is present on the path
`C:\Users\helen\WORKSPACE\Java\osing\osing-ejb\build.xml`

I think this path is incorrect for the file specify.